VS2017 - The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document
On a C++ solution, with multiple projects in it, I get this error when I set a breakpoint in any of the C++ dependency's source code :
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document
Let's say the solution is as follow :
Sol
  ProjA
  ProjB
  ProjC

ProjA contains the main entry point. Setting breaking points on this project source code works. The vcxproj file for ProjA contains the following (only relevent parts) :

   <ProjectConfiguration Include="Unicode Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Unicode Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>

...

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Unicode Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <UseOfMfc>Dynamic</UseOfMfc>
    <UseOfAtl>false</UseOfAtl>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    <CLRSupport>true</CLRSupport>
  </PropertyGroup>

... 

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Unicode Debug|Win32'">
    <OutDir>$(SolutionDir)build\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(SolutionDir)build\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\temp3\</IntDir>
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
    <EnableManagedIncrementalBuild>true</EnableManagedIncrementalBuild>
    <TargetName>program</TargetName>
  </PropertyGroup>

...

<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Unicode Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>[omitted]</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;_MBCS;_AFXDLL;WIN32;_WINDOWS;UNICODE;_DONTUSECRASHHANDLER;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <BasicRuntimeChecks>Default</BasicRuntimeChecks>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebugDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
      <RuntimeTypeInfo>true</RuntimeTypeInfo>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>stdafx.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
      <PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile>$(IntDir)Poems.pch</PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile>
      <AssemblerListingLocation>$(IntDir)</AssemblerListingLocation>
      <ObjectFileName>$(IntDir)</ObjectFileName>
      <ProgramDataBaseFileName>$(IntDir)</ProgramDataBaseFileName>
      <BrowseInformation>false</BrowseInformation>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
      <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
      <CompileAs>CompileAsCpp</CompileAs>
      <CompileAsManaged>true</CompileAsManaged>
      <MultiProcessorCompilation>false</MultiProcessorCompilation>
      <LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard>
      <FloatingPointModel>Fast</FloatingPointModel>
      <ExceptionHandling>false</ExceptionHandling>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>[omitted]</AdditionalDependencies>
      <OutputFile>$(OutDir)program.exe</OutputFile>
      <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(OutDir);%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories);..\bin</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <ProgramDatabaseFile>$(OutDir)smget.pdb</ProgramDatabaseFile>
      <GenerateMapFile>true</GenerateMapFile>
      <MapFileName>$(OutDir)smget.map</MapFileName>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <EntryPointSymbol>wWinMainCRTStartup</EntryPointSymbol>
      <TargetMachine>MachineX86</TargetMachine>
      <AssemblyDebug>true</AssemblyDebug>
      <LinkTimeCodeGeneration>UseFastLinkTimeCodeGeneration</LinkTimeCodeGeneration>
    </Link>
    <Midl>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <MkTypLibCompatible>true</MkTypLibCompatible>
      <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
      <TargetEnvironment>Win32</TargetEnvironment>
      <TypeLibraryName>.\..\Install/Poems.tlb</TypeLibraryName>
      <HeaderFileName />
    </Midl>
    <PostBuildEvent>
      <Message>
      </Message>
      <Command>
      </Command>
    </PostBuildEvent>
    <ResourceCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <Culture>0x0809</Culture>
    </ResourceCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>


However, ProjB breakpoint does not work when running Local Windows Debugger and I get the mentionned error message. Using VS2017, I've checked C/C++ -> General -> Debug Info Format is /Zi, no CLR. Linker -> debugging pdb for ProjB is created at $(OutDir), General Debug Info is set to /DEBUG. There is also a map file created.
I've cleaned the build folder mutiple time. I've uninstalled the program (because a version of that program was installed) to avoid dll being loaded from elsewhere.
